# MVC Error page not showing up, how to fix?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this line in my web.config:

```
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect"/>
```

The error hits the error.cshtml page and sends an error email from the error page, but the error.cshtml page doesn't render on the screen, it stays on the current page.

Here is the code in the controller that causes the error.  I know how to fix the error, I have it breaking on purpose to try to get the error.cshtml page to show up.

```
            public ViewResult UpdateCountySessionVariables(string countyId)
    {
        //was viewresult

        CountyModel countyModel = new CountyModel();
        countyModel = _countyRepo.GetCounty(Int32.Parse(countyId));
        Session["CountyName"] = countyModel.Name;
        Session["CountyId"] = countyId;

        int newCountyId = Int32.Parse(Session["CountyId"].ToString());
        int currentFiscalYearId = Int32.Parse(Session["CurrentFiscalYearId"].ToString());

        ModelState.Clear();
        AnnualReportModel annualReportModel = _annualReportRepo.GetAnnualReport(newCountyId, currentFiscalYearId);
        AnnualReportViewModel annualReportViewModel = new AnnualReportViewModel();
                    annualReportViewModel.AnnualReportModel = _annualReportRepo.GetAnnualReport(annualReportModel.Id);

            string fiscalYearStartYear = annualReportViewModel.AnnualReportModel.FiscalYearModel.Name.Substring(0, 4);
            string fiscalYearEndYear = annualReportViewModel.AnnualReportModel.FiscalYearModel.Name.Substring(5, 4);

            annualReportViewModel.fiscalYearStartYear = fiscalYearStartYear;
            annualReportViewModel.fiscalYearEndYear = fiscalYearEndYear;
            annualReportViewModel.Counties = _countyRepo.GetCounties();

            var CountyName = Session["CountyName"].ToString();

        return View("Index", annualReportViewModel);

    }
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: Which web.config is it in? Also, is the error being thrown by an async (AJAX) call?

Comment: Show the action method that gets hit that's responsible for returning the error view.

Comment: it's in the main web.config.

Comment: The function is being called by Ajax.